# Python: list destructing assignment gets wrong

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code I want to sort list `d`, `e`, `f` by the elements in `a`, `b`, `c`. However, the resulted `d`, `e`, `f` have duplicated values, which should not occur because this is simply a sorting. 
I have found out that the problem is in the line (Let's call it e-line.)

```
[ad[i], be[i], cf[i]] = [m, n, o]
```

before this line, i.e., the result of line (Let's call it c-line.)

```
m, n, o = sorted([ad[i], be[i], cf[i]], key=itemgetter(0))
```

is correct, but when it goes to the e-line, problem comes. I have captured a screenshot when `i = 1`, before e-line:

[image: before]

and a screenshot after e-line:

[image: after]

See? Not only `ad[1]` and `cf[1]` are duplicated, but also `m` and `o` are the same after the step.
Could you tell me what happens during this step? Why the assignment result in duplicated values?

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

a = [0.06546757, 0.98135887, 0.94941228]
b = [0.41770855, 0.7188204, 0.4161441]
c = [0.64173702, 0.71125552, 0.11180992]
d = [0.29584944, 0.23759218, 0.89771063]
e = [0.97220382, 0.06904977, 0.81744618]
f = [0.10343642, 0.05042443, 0.56769208]

# Group a and d, b and e, c and f
ad = np.transpose([a, d])
be = np.transpose([b, e])
cf = np.transpose([c, f])

for i in range(3):
    m, n, o = sorted([ad[i], be[i], cf[i]], key=itemgetter(0))  # Sort by element in a, b, c
    [ad[i], be[i], cf[i]] = [m, n, o]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should write this up as a [MCVE]

Comment: BTW you can completely get rid of `m`, `n`, `o`: `(a, b, c) = sorted([a, b, c], ...)` should suffice.

Comment: @9000 Well, sure, but I use `m`, `n`, `o` simply for debugging, which makes it easier to explain my code.

Comment: `m`, `n`, and `o` are all views. When you assign back into `ad`, `be`, and `cf`, you clobber the parts `m`, `n`, and `o` were taking views of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assign copies of `m,n,o`, the duplication goes away (I think):

```
print(ad, be, cf)
for i in range(3):
    m, n, o = sorted([ad[i], be[i], cf[i]], key=itemgetter(0))  # Sort by element in a, b, c
    [ad[i], be[i], cf[i]] = [m.copy(), n.copy(), o.copy()]
print()
print(ad, be, cf)
# print(m,n,o)
```

produces:

```
[[ 0.06546757  0.29584944]
 [ 0.71125552  0.05042443]
 [ 0.11180992  0.56769208]] 

[[ 0.41770855  0.97220382]
 [ 0.7188204   0.06904977]
 [ 0.4161441   0.81744618]] 

[[ 0.64173702  0.10343642]
 [ 0.98135887  0.23759218]
 [ 0.94941228  0.89771063]]
```

Your example could be simpler and easier to read.  For example with integers instead of the floats.

I didn't work this out in an detail, but the duplication indicated that one or more value was being over written.  `m,n,o` are 2 element lists.  So I just guessed that this would be a good place to put the `copy`.